# Running Gitlab and Maven repo on the same server

Tags: gitlab, maven

I was wondering, I am currently setting up Gitlab for versioning and Artefactory for Maven - Gitlab is currently running on a VM on my server.

What would you do, make a new VM for Artefactory or use the existing one to have them run on the same server?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I'm sorry, I think this is off topic `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`

Comment: It's true. Sorry about that. To be fair I wasn't really thinking when I asked this, must be the lack of morning coffee. There's a whole bunch of things to consider now that I woke up properly, such as recovery time from backups, maintenance effort and security concerns. Thanks anyway!